# how to do bind data with material-ui table and also pagination

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mern

I have facing an issue with binding my data with the material-UI table
(1) first thing it is just showing the product name and when I am trying to add product price so it is now binding there
(2) also I have done pagination on my server-side but when i change the page of my table it is just showing the first 5 rows [image]

in this image, you can easily see that just names are showing on the table, and in the console, there are two arrays showing, the first one occurred when the page was loaded and the second one occurred when I change my pagination, check the pagination in the page.

here is my table code

```
products.map((row) => (
      <TableRow key={row.name}>
        <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
          {row.name}
          
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell style={{ width: 160 }} align="right">
          {row.calories}
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell style={{ width: 160 }} align="right">
          {row.fat}
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    ))}
```

here i am fetching data

```
 const dispatch = useDispatch(); 

    const {loading, products, error, productCount} = useSelector(state => state.products);

    useEffect(()=>{
         dispatch(getProducts());
     
    },[dispatch])
```

I am also attaching the material-UI link here which I am using, I just simple copied and paste code the
on the page of material-UI, you can see `Custom pagination actions`

https://mui.com/components/tables/#main-content

Comment: You need to update the redux state onPageChange that way it will bind correctly

Answer (score 0):

For Pagination, you can use DataGrid in MUI,
First, you have to define a constant for columns naming like below then use the MUI DataGrid

```
 const columns = [
      { field: "name", headerName: "Name" },
      { field: "calories", headerName: "Calories" },
      { field: "fat", headerName: "Fat" },
 ]
 
 <DataGrid
     rows={products}
     columns={columns}
     pageSize={5}
     rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 15]}
     checkboxSelection={false}
 />
```

Here Products is the list you are providing the page to render.
And you have to handle the listing rows pagination by `Top, Skip` Strategy

Comment: I don't have Datagrid I am fetching data by `useEffect ` if you see my map function so it is mapping by products which is dispatched by dispatch function

Comment: But you said you want to implement pagination.. That can be done by MUI data grid. Plus you don't need to map your data, Data grid will do it for you.

Comment: i already did pagination on backend